# Type 'Subscription' is not assignable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hello the code below performs a rest call to an endpoint on node.js backend in this ionic app however when I run the code it returns me the following error how can I fix this?

**Error:**

```
ERROR in src/app/services/user.service.ts(22,5): error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
[ng]   Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'
```

**TypeScript Code:**

```
 //Metodo che esegue il login dell'utente
  loginService(username: string, password: string):Observable<any>
  { 
    return this.http.post(url+"/login",{"Username": username,"Password": password}).subscribe((val) => {console.log("POST call successful value returned in body",val);}, response => {  console.log("POST call in error", response); }, () => { console.log("The POST observable is now completed."); });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error message is clear enough: you declare an observable, but return a subscription. You should simply do

```
loginService (Username: string, Password: string): Observable<any> { 
    return this.http.post(url + "/login", { Username, Password });
}
```

If you want your `loginService` do do some postprocessing of the results, you should use some RxJS operators in the pipe. Something like

```
return this.http.post(/* args */).pipe(
    tap(val => console.log('Success message. ', val),
    catchError(err => {
        console.error('Error message. ', err);
        return throwError(err);
    }))
```

Comment: Additionally, you can also handle the finally/final by adding `finalize(() => {...})` pipe operator.

Answer (score 0):

`http` call will return an `Observable`. You mentioned the return type as `observable` but actually you are subscribing it from that method. Service methods are not supposed to subscribe. Subscription should be done from `component` label.

```
//Metodo che esegue il login dell'utente
loginService(username: string, password: string):Observable<any>
{ 
  return this.http.post(url+"/login",{"Username": username,"Password": password});
}
```

Subscribe/ Consume it form your component

```
this.yourService.loginService('test', 'test').subscribe(
    res => console.log(res), 
    err=> console.log(err)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.http.post(url+"/login",{"Username": username,"Password": password})` is `Observable<any>`
But return type of `Observable.subscribe` is `Subscription`
So your function is wrong, it should be

```
loginService(username: string, password: string):Observable<any>
  { 
    return this.http.post(url+"/login",{"Username": username,"Password": password})
  }

class anotherClass {
    constructor(_loginService: loginService) {
        _loginService.subscribe((val) => {
            console.log("POST call successful value returned in body",val);
        }, response => {
            console.log("POST call in error", response); 
        }, () => {
            console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
        });
    }
}
```